# How to sort filenames alphabetically in rtorrent?

Tags: rtorrent

When I open the file list of a torrent, filenames appear randomly:

```
*** some.series.name - 1 season ***

               Cmp Pri  Size   Filename
Peer list        0     744.3 M| some.series.name.S01E20 (rus,eng).mkv                                                                                                                                               
                 0     742.2 M| some.series.name.S01E07 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
Info            43     734.3 M| some.series.name.S01E19 (rus,eng).mkv
                 1     725.0 M| some.series.name.S01E10 (rus,eng).mkv
File list       16     721.4 M| some.series.name.S01E08 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
                17     720.1 M| some.series.name.S01E18 (rus,eng).mkv
Tracker list   100 hig 700.8 M| some.series.name.S01E02 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
                87     696.8 M| some.series.name.S01E12 (rus,eng).mkv
Chunks seen    100 hig 695.5 M| some.series.name.S01E01 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
                 9     693.8 M| some.series.name.S01E11 (rus,eng).mkv
Transfer list    0     691.9 M| some.series.name.S01E15 (rus,eng).mkv
                 0     632.9 M| some.series.name.S01E16 (rus,eng).mkv
                19     601.2 M| some.series.name.S01E06 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
                 0     592.9 M| some.series.name.S01E04 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
                 0     589.1 M| some.series.name.S01E03 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
                 0     573.5 M| some.series.name.S01E14 (rus,eng).mkv
                 0     571.7 M| some.series.name.S01E09 (rus,eng).mkv
                 0     560.7 M| some.series.name.S01E13 (rus,eng).mkv
                 0     556.7 M| some.series.name.S01E17 (rus,eng).mkv
                 0     553.3 M| some.series.name.S01E05 (rus,ukr,eng).mkv
```

I want them sorted alphabetically. How can I do that?

Comment: There seems to have been an open request for this for a long time: https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/issues/93

Answer (score 1):

You can press `2` to go to the “sort by name” view.